# In compound verbs, what's the difference between ～過ぎる and ～過ごす?

Tags: compound-verbs

For example, 食べ過ぎる and 寝過ごす: if I say 食べ過ごす and 寝過ぎる instead, is it the same thing?

I already know 寝過ごす is a transitive verb and I think 寝過ぎる is not and I don't even know if 食べ過ごす is right. However, they're just examples and I want to know what to do with the rest of the verbs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least as a suffixing verb in the present-day language, ～過ごす no longer has any "over-" meaning as ～過ぎる does, so the two are totally distinct grammars.

**V 過ごす** only means "V to miss something" or "V to dispense with something", thus:

- 寝過ぎる means you *sleep too much* (that causes headache, maybe), but;
- 寝過ごす means you *sleep until it is too late*, e.g. missed the station or school

---

- やり過ぎる means you *overdo*, but;
- やり過ごす means you do without dealing with something, that is, *let go (past)* or *avert*

---

- 見過ぎる means you over-look, or *overdo looking/watching*, but;
- 見過ごす means you *overlook*, in the sense failing to notice

---

Similarly, 食べ過ぎる is just "eating too much", but I have never heard of 食べ過ごす as a single verb, except for a collocation of 食べ + 過ごす "to pass time eating —".